# WPF - how to do binding the right way for a particular scenario?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I'm pretty new to WPF (moving from WinForms). I'm trying to transfer some scenario from a WinForms application to a WPF one:

1. A window has a ListView control with 3 columns.
2. There is a button there to add new rows to that ListView.
3. The first and the second columns contain the ComboBox control.
4. The third column must contain different controls but just one at a time is visible. Which one is visible, it depends on the selected value of the ComboBox at the first column.
5. The content of the ComboBox at the second column changes every time a user selects a value from the ComboBox at the first column.

The general scenario is: a user selects a type from the list of types from the first ComboBox, after that the second ComboBox changes its content to a list of supported operations for the selected type and the third column at that time must change its content to display a control that supports the input for that type.

I know how to implement it using WinForms but I have no idea yet how to do it using WPF. Can someone help me to implement it or can anyone help with the information that facilitate implementing that?

I have the code so far:

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, args);
    }
}

public class RecordFilter : ViewModelBase
{
    private static readonly ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<PropertyInfo, string>> ColumnAliases =
        new ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<PropertyInfo, string>>(Card.ColumnAliases);

    private KeyValuePair<PropertyInfo, string> _currentSelectedProperty;

    public IEnumerable<OperationInfo> Operations
    {
        get
        {
            return Operations.GetOperationInfosForType(GetTypeUnwrapNullable(SelectedProperty.Key.PropertyType));
        }
    }

    public OperationInfo SelectedOperation { get; set; }

    public KeyValuePair<PropertyInfo, string> SelectedProperty
    {
        get { return _currentSelectedProperty; }
        set
        {
            _currentSelectedProperty = value;

            OnPropertyChanged("Operations");
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<PropertyInfo, string>> Properties
    {
        get { return ColumnAliases; }
    }

    //DateTime or int or float, depends on the selected property type
    //public object PropertyValue { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the XAML code:

```html
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Converters="clr-namespace:App.Converters" x:Class="App.DialogWindows.CardFilterWindow"
        Title="Search filters" Height="347" Width="628" x:Name="wdw" ShowInTaskbar="False" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Converters:NotNullObjectToEnabledConverter x:Key="NotNullObjectToEnabledConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <DockPanel>
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="Auto">
            <Button x:Name="bnOK" Margin="5" Width="41" Content="OK" IsDefault="True" Click="bnOK_Click"/>
            <Button x:Name="bnCancel" Margin="5" Content="Отмена" IsCancel="True"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Filters, ElementName=wdw}" Name="LvExpr" DataContext="{Binding Filters, ElementName=wdw}">
            <ListView.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.Resources>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Alias" Width="210">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding Properties}"
                                    DisplayMemberPath="Value"
                                    SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedProperty, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                    />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Operation" Width="150">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding Operations}"
                                    DisplayMemberPath="OperationAlias"
                                    SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedOperation, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Value" Width="100">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Text="ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="33">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Tag="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" Click="BnDelete_Click" ToolTip="Delete filter">
                                    <Image Source="delete.ico" Height="16" Width="16"/>
                                </Button>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <GridViewColumnHeader>
                            <DataGridCell>
                                <Button Click="ButtonAdd_Click" Height="22" Padding="0" ToolTip="Add filter">
                                    <Image Source="plus.ico" Focusable="False"/>
                                </Button>
                            </DataGridCell>
                        </GridViewColumnHeader>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Please show your progress so far, otherwise you'll much probably get your question closed. Also, WPF is all about DataBinding. The idea is that you need a ViewModel that does the logic, not the UI in code behind or otherwise.

Comment: Actually, I've managed to implement almost everything I described except for the showing a proper control at the third column. I do not know how to show TextEdit control for the string type (when a user selects that type in the ComboBox) or show DateTimePicker control for the DateTime type...

Comment: @ArlenKeshabyan please post the relevant code and XAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view-model, set up the list properties, and filter them out accordingly when the selected value changes (via the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event).

See [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17946.cascading-comboboxes-in-wpf-using-mvvm.aspx) post for a comprehensive example. It uses a technique called MVVM that is used extensively with WPF and stands for ModelViewViewModel. I highly recommend you to learn this technique and utilize it in your XAML-related projects.
[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial) is one quick start tutorial, out of the many on the net.

Comment: Thanks for the links! They are really useful, but I've already implemented the cascading ComboBoxes using ViewModel and proper binding. The only thing left is showing different sorts of controls at the third column...